# How fast (slow) is Quercus PHP on Resin Open Source as opposed to Resin Professional?

Tags: java, php, resin, quercus

The clever folks at Caucho are quick to point out that Quercus is 3x-5x faster than straight mod_php (without APC). But digging deeper in the documentation, you'll see that the PHP-to-bytecode compilation is only available in Resin Pro ($699).

What I'd like to know is, how fast (i.e. how slow) is Resin Open Source for executing PHP code?

Yes I know I could just test it, it depends on the application, it depends on the environment, blah blah blah. But I just need a single anecdotal data-point from anyone who's done it before, whether it's statistically significant or not... doesn't matter!

Comment: This looks like a licensing issue more than a performance issue. I could be wrong, but it looks like the open source version is for evaluation and open source projects only. If yours doesn't fall under either category, you'll probably have to buy a license either way.

Comment: @mf: I don't think it changes the question all that much. How much slower is the performance on the open source version which happens to be for evaluation and open source projects only, versus the licensed version? Are you saying the code and hence the performance are exactly the same regardless of the license?

Comment: First test (using microtime) on console php applications (java -jar quercus.jar some.php) shows that the default php is significantly faster.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quercus is independent of Resin (Open Source or Commercial), and it is  open source itself.

We run Quercus on Jetty and Tomcat, and in most apps we use it, is at least 2 times faster than the mod_php, not to mention all the security advantages running apps on the JVM.

The Commercial Resin is indeed even faster, but since most of our customers didn't like to buy the extra license, Tomcat is good enough for most of them. For us is very convenient since we don't have to use Apache HTTPD in front of Tomcat, so the maintenance costs are quite low.

Comment: Open source doesn't mean free.